# Can the type of a previously defined extern variable be inferred without using decltype

Tags: c++, c++11, extern, decltype

```
// header

int extern has_a_type; // (1) extern declaration

// implementation

decltype(has_a_type)   // (2) unnecessarily verbose type inference code
has_a_type;            // (3) definition
```

I understand that I can use `decltype` so I do not actually have to type (or even know, to some extent) the type of a extern declared (1) variable when defining (3) (and possibly initializing) it. However `decltype` forces me to write out the name of the variable (potentially fully qualified and long) twice (2).

How can I avoid writing it twice? Something along the lines of `auto has_a_type;` (which does, of course, not work).

Comment: And I do not want to use the obvious macro solution.

Comment: @bolov Because `auto has_a_type;` doesn't have anything in it to tell the compiler what `auto` should be deduced as.

Comment: @bolov I mean `auto has_a_type;` instead of `decltype(has_a_type) has_a_type;` as used above.

Comment: @bolov His issue is `decltype` requires the use of `has_a_type` twice on the same line (`decltype(has_a_type) has_a_type;`).  `auto has_a_type;` only has to specify it once, but wont work as there is nothing to deduce the type with.

Comment: @SergeyA All static class member variables are implicitly extern, so this is quite a common case.

Comment: @bolov Judging from your false edit, you didn't get it completely.

Comment: @not-a-user, yep, and this is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @not-a-user ok... what I didn't get?

Comment: Hack: `int& has_a_type() { static int foo = some_value; return foo; }`.  Then you just use it as `has_a_type()` in all included locations ;)

Comment: Honestly, I don't see why use `decltype` at all. If you erroneously define `double has_a_type;` then it's a hard error then and there.

Comment: @bolov You introduced a syntax error. I intentionally split the definition on two lines.

Comment: @not-a-user it's not obvious imho that's what you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't - facetiously because nobody has convinced the standards committee as to the merit of being able to write

```
int extern has_a_type;
auto has_a_type;
```

despite its tractability. It might turn out that

```
decltype(auto) has_a_type;
```

would be necessary in order to disambiguate type deduction from initialisers and then, unfortuantely, we're not too far removed from the repetitious `decltype(has_a_type)` that's already available.

Comment: Upvoted, but I would argue against `auto has_a_type;`. Consider this: `int external var;` ... `auto external = 2.4` . Wouldn't it be surprising and inconsistent with how `auto` works? Here `auto external` is `int` although the initializer produces a `double`.